# Javascript - escaping specific characters

Tags: php, javascript, delimiter

I'm using php to create some strings I need to split() with javascript.

example:

```
<?php
$string = "Apples";
$string .= "|"; // delimiter
$string .= "Oranges";
$string .= "|"; // delimiter
$string .= "Grapes";
?>

and here I split the string with JS:
<script>
var str = <?php echo $string; ?>
var fruitsArray = str.split('|'); 
for(var i=0; i<fruitsArray.length; i++){
 // do stuff here
}
</script>
```

In this case, the **pipe character** is the delimiter.  But I could use any special character.
My problem is when the **$string** has a character I use for splitting AND it's also part of the non-delimiter portion.

For example:

```
<?php
$string = "Apples";
$string .= "|"; // delimiter
$string .= "Oranges";
$string .= "|"; // delimiter
$string .= "Grapes";
$string .= "|"; // delimiter
$string .= "Berries: blue|black"; // pipe exists, but not meant to be a delimiter
?>
```

It's circumstantial only, but does happen to me.  My delimiters sometimes find their way into the fruits. (though I am only using fruits as an example)

I feel I need to convert my designated delimiters to another format before javascript gets a hold of it.  But I'm not certain.

Anyone know what's best in this situation?

Comment: Why not skip the packing/unpacking entirely? `<?php $strings = array('Apples', 'Oranges', 'Grapes', 'Berries: blue|black'); ?> var fruitArray = <?php echo json_encode($strings); ?>;`

Comment: If you're going to `echo` the `$string` directly into your JS why don't you just `echo` an array literal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try use a more mature way of marshaling variables into javascript. Like json.

To convert a php array to json: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

```
echo json_encode(array('Apples', 'Oranges'));
```

To get an array from json in javascript:

- With jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/
- or just use eval() in javascript (**WARNING**: Unsafe - use ONLY if you TRUST the data source - don't use if the string is user-supplied), or implicitly eval: `var fruitArray = <?php echo json_encode(array('Apples', 'Oranges')); ?>;`

Answer (score 0):

To me the quickest solution is to devise a delimiter that is entirely unique even if it is "|%^*".

To me the best solution is to develop a [context free grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar).  That is define all of the types of words explicitly.

for example

```
delimeter :: |
list :: (element |)*
element :: [\w]+ (: list)*
```

doing a clean design where you define everything explicitly will allow you to cover border cases.

One example is in your example you have a delimeter in an element, but you need to find a way to differentiate that.  My solution was that if the delimeter is in an element it must have parenthesis around the entire list.  Otherwise you have no idea where the element ends and the list resumes.

If I wasn't clear you can always read that wikipedia page about grammars, or do research online.

I hope I was clear.